# Inconsistent behavior when accessing a vector passed by reference

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, pass-by-reference

I have implemented a function to merge two sorted vectors (v1 and v2) into a bigger sorted one (fa) by passing the vectors by const reference to it and comparing which value is the smallest so the bigger one can be sorted too. It works sometimes but sometimes when the first access to the passed vectors happens I get a segmentation fault.

Here is the code for the function:

```
void merge(const vector<int>& v1, 
          const vector<int>& v2,
          vector<int>& fa)
{
int i = 0, p1 = 0, p2 = 0;

while(p2 < v2.size() && p1 < v1.size())
{
    if(v1[p1] < v2[p2]){
        fa[i] = v1[p1];
        p1++;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        fa[i] = v2[p2];
        p2++;
        i++;
    }
}
//cover the cases where one of the arrays is done and the other isn't
while(p1 == v1.size() && p2 < v2.size()) 
{
    fa[i] = v2[p2];
    p2++;
    i++;
}
while(p2 == v2.size() && p1 < v1.size())
{
    fa[i] = v1[p1];
    p1++;
    i++;
}
}
```

Initially I tried using iterators, but it was inconsistent too, so changed to just integers probably because the iterators disappeared after the first function call.

Also when I pass by value it never gives me a segmentation fault.

TLDR -  accessing a vector container passed by (const) reference sometimes give me seg fault, why is that?

Comment: Is `fa` guaranteed to have size of at least `v1.size() + v2.size()` reserved? Why not just return a vector instead of using output parameter?

Comment: Can you narrow down what's happening when it segfaults, e.g. run under gdb and look at the backtrace?

Comment: It seems to work: https://ideone.com/eyxTP0

Comment: Like @Yksisarvinen said, make sure `fa` was allocated `v1.size() + v2.size()` slots. You cannot use `reserve` since `reserve` just allocates the space but the array is still empty. You can initialize `v = std::vector<int>(v1.size() + v2.size(), 0)` and pass this as your `fa` argument.

Comment: Well, changed it to doing everything inside the function and return a vector and it works fine, but the fact that this is inconsistent is still weird to me. I passed a fa that was declared as vector<int>fa(v1.size()+v2.size()) to it. I will double-check if something outside is wrong

Comment: @lightalchemist `resize` is the correct function to do this.

Comment: Worked on my machine.  I think the bug is in the code not provided.

Comment: @mch Yes, `resize` can work. I was referring to `reserve`. Also, you can allocate that number of slots right from the start, although I would agree assigning the value is probably redundant and wasteful.

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work when I pass as a reference. I will add the rest of the code to the post

Comment: Be careful, as you may be utilizing some Undefined Behaviour. Returning std::vector is much safer (you are the one in control) and much more readable (quoting Uncle Bob: "Output parameters are a lie").

Comment: It works now, when I reordered some things in main. Thanks for the fast response guys! I don't understand how manipulating an outside of function container is undefined behavior, although they tend to be much more complex than normal c arrays. I will do some reading about output parameters I guess to see if I see if I can convince myself. Thanks again!